# Looking for Pythonic Way to Delete Rows in a Pandas Dataframe if Any "Cells" Match One of 3 Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a more pythonic (and faster!) way to clear out any row that has one of three strings in any row. I have code that works, but is SOOOO slow!

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
# Check out each row
for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    for index in range(df2.shape[1]): 
        # Check out values in each column

        # if it's 98 or 99, drop it
        if df2.iloc[i,index] == '98.00':
            df2.drop(i)
            print('dropped row ', i, ' due to high value')
        elif df2.iloc[i,index] == '99.00':
            df2.drop(i)
            print('dropped row ', i, ' due to high value')                

        # or if the value is the default text null value, drop it
        elif df2.iloc[i,index] == '#NULL!':
            df2.drop(i)
            print('dropped row ', i, 'due to null value')
```

Comment: It is extremely rare that you should have to use `iterrows` and is frowned upon by experienced pandas users, because of the exact problem you are facing speed... but it also so much easier to read/write if you learn pandas methods. There is almost always a pandas vectorized method you can use like `.isin`, so always google your problem and look for StackOverFlow answers that solve your problem using vectorized pandas methods.  Sometimes you might have to use list comprehension or other techniques if your problem is specific.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. How do I find a list of vectorized methods? I am still fairly new to Python, and simply don't know how to search to find ideas, so any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` method:

```
df = df[~df['COLUMN'].isin(['LIST','OF','STRINGS'])]
```

Comment: There are 27 columns, so listing them is something that I don't want to do. I'm looking for code that will work without knowing the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, but you can used filters with |(or) to store the rows you want to drop, then use drop on the df.

Such as:

drop_row = df.loc[(df['some_column] > something) | (df['some_column] > something)

df.drop(index = drop_row.index, inplace = True)

Answer (score 0):

`isin` combined with `any` should work:

```
df = df[~df.isin(["98.0", "99.0", "#NULL!"]).any(axis="columns")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use drop() and isin() function (previously suggested), I would reccomend:

```
df.drop(index=df[df.isin(["98.00", "99.00", "#NULL!"]).any(1)].index, inplace=True)
```

which is a shorter way to express:

```
df.drop(index=df[((df == "98.00") | (df == "99.00") | (df == '#NULL!')).any(1)].index, inplace=True)
```

Hereby is described how the code works:

1. The indexes where any of the requested condition is verified are
   selected first.
2. Then the index of the selection is used in the drop function to
   remove the related rows in the dataframe.
3. "inplace=True" is
   necessary to permanently perform the drop in the df. You can replace by "inplace=False" if you want only to show the drop results as temporary, e.g. through a print() function.